# 32 bit Multiplication Assembly iApx88

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to do 32 bit multiplication. I can not understand the problem. Answer does not matches with the calculator

```
[org 0x0100]
mov cx,0
mov cx,32
mov dx,[multiplier]
mov bx,[multiplier+2]

check_bit:
shr bx,1
rcr dx,1
jnc skip
mov ax,[multiplicand+6]
add [result+6],ax
mov ax,[multiplicand+4]
adc [result+4],ax
mov ax,[multiplicand+2]
adc [result+2],ax
mov ax,[multiplicand]
adc [result],ax

skip:
shl word[multiplicand+6],1
rcl word[multiplicand+4],1
rcl word[multiplicand+2],1
rcl word[multiplicand],1
dec cl
jnz check_bit

mov ax,0x4c00
int 0x21
multiplicand: dd 0x00000000 , 0x98765432
multiplier: dd 0x12345678
result: dd 0 , 0
```

Comment: _does not match_ is not a good problem description. What's your input and expected and actual output. Also, learn to use a debugger and comment your code especially if you want others to help. PS: any particular reason why you avoid `MUL` instruction?

Comment: Use [edit] to make this a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems arise because you don't treat your numbers the way they are stored in memory.
You do it OK for the multiplier, but not for the multiplicand nor the result!

Values are stored in memory in **little endian** format and so the first addition is done on the lowest word in memory, climbing up to the highest word:

```
mov ax,[multiplicand]
add [result],ax
mov ax,[multiplicand+2]
adc [result+2],ax
mov ax,[multiplicand+4]
adc [result+4],ax
mov ax,[multiplicand+6]
adc [result+6],ax
```

Same thing with doubling the multiplicand. You start at the low end and insert the CF in each of the higher words:

```
skip:
    shl word[multiplicand],1
    rcl word[multiplicand+2],1
    rcl word[multiplicand+4],1
    rcl word[multiplicand+6],1
```

---

> ```
> multiplicand: dd 0x00000000 , 0x98765432
> ```

There's a good chance that this multiplicand is not what you want?
For a 32-bit multiplication next makes more sense!

```
multiplicand: dd 0x98765432 , 0x00000000
```